# Magento 2 Cron : How to add yes/no Configuration in Backend Stores -> Config -> Advanced -> System under Cron group?

Tags: magento2, admin, configuration, cron

> I have created a custom cron and I want to add yes/no config field under Stores -> Config -> Advanced
> -> System -> Cron group

**I'm copying the `/vendor/magento/module-cron/etc/adminhtml/system.xml` file in my custom module as below and added one yes/no field but it's not working.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="system">
            <group id="cron" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="15" showInDefault="1">
                <label>Cron (Scheduled Tasks)</label>
                <comment>For correct URLs generated during cron runs please make sure that Web &gt; Secure and Unsecure Base URLs are explicitly set. All the times are in minutes.</comment>
                <group id="yes_no" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1">
                    <label>Cron configuration options for group:</label>
                    <field id="yes_no_field" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" canRestore="1">
                        <label>Yes/NO Cron</label>
                        <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    </field>
                    <field id="schedule_generate_every" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" canRestore="1">
                        <label>Generate Schedules Every</label>
                        <validate>validate-zero-or-greater validate-digits</validate>
                    </field>
                    <field id="schedule_ahead_for" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" canRestore="1">
                        <label>Schedule Ahead for</label>
                        <validate>validate-zero-or-greater validate-digits</validate>
                    </field>
                    <field id="schedule_lifetime" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" canRestore="1">
                        <label>Missed if Not Run Within</label>
                        <validate>validate-zero-or-greater validate-digits</validate>
                    </field>
                    <field id="history_cleanup_every" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" canRestore="1">
                        <label>History Cleanup Every</label>
                        <validate>validate-zero-or-greater validate-digits</validate>
                    </field>
                    <field id="history_success_lifetime" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" canRestore="1">
                        <label>Success History Lifetime</label>
                        <validate>validate-zero-or-greater validate-digits</validate>
                    </field>
                    <field id="history_failure_lifetime" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="60" showInDefault="1" canRestore="1">
                        <label>Failure History Lifetime</label>
                        <validate>validate-zero-or-greater validate-digits</validate>
                    </field>
                    <field id="use_separate_process" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="70" showInDefault="1" canRestore="1">
                        <label>Use Separate Process</label>
                        <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    </field>
                </group>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**Let me know if anyone has any ideas**

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve?

To hide a config based on the value of another field, you would a depends node inside the field node, like this:

```
<field>
    <depends>
        <field id="your_target">1</field>
    </depends>
</field>
```

Comment: please check updated question